# Salesforce: Is it a good idea to use SOQL to enforce security and limit record access?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

This is more of a best practices question. Our org currently has "public read" permissions on our org wide defaults for custom objects. We cannot make this private because of the way its working now for internal employees or rather we are trying to avoid this.

I am also creating a customer portal with custom visual force pages...where I display data using SOQL queries.

Is it a good idea to add a clause on the SOQL query to return only those records where the account id matches the logged in user's acount id?

I did it and it works fine...But are there any pitfalls to this method that I am overlooking?

Thanks,
Calvin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [Visualforce Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=%7C%7Cshared%7Csharing%7CSharing%7Cshare%7CShared%7CShare%7Cshares%7CShares)

> Because standard controllers execute in user mode, in which the
>   permissions, field-level security, and sharing rules of the current
>   user are enforced, extending a standard controller allows you to build
>   a Visualforce page that respects user permissions. Although the
>   extension class executes in system mode, the standard controller
>   executes in user mode. As with custom controllers, you can specify
>   whether a user can execute methods in a controller extension based on
>   the user's profile.

I believe the idea being, as long as your classes are `public with sharing` then permissions should be enforced and records should not be returned that the user cannot see (same with fields on a record).

per the [Apex Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=public%7CPublic%7Cpublication%7C%7C%7C%7Cshared%7Csharing%7CSharing%7Cshare%7CShared%7CShare%7Cshares%7CShares)

> Apex generally runs in system context; that is, the current user's
>   permissions, field-level security, and sharing rules aren’t taken into
>   account during code execution.

Use the **`with sharing`** keywords when declaring a class to enforce the sharing rules that apply to the current user. For example:

```
public with sharing class sharingClass {

// Code here 


}
```

Use the **`without sharing`** keywords when declaring a class to ensure that the sharing rules for the current user are not enforced. For example:

```
public without sharing class noSharing {

// Code here 


}
```

Otherwise you would have to spend hours ensuring that the right permissions applied at exactly the right time for the right user.  It would almost completely defeat the purpose of a visualforce page!

Comment: Hi Mike,Thanks for this great reply. I am using the "with sharing" keywords in my controller class declaration. The org wide default setting is public on the custom objects that I need to display in the Customer portal. So by default when a user views the report page, he can see all records. What else can be done by me in the config to ensure that a user cannot see any records which do not belong to the same Account as his. This has been a real problem for me and I have read quite a bit of documentation. But with our sharing model, it has been quite a challenge.

Comment: I'm not too well versed on how the customer portal portion of the Salesforce CRM works.  We use it, but in a limited capacity and I have not had to work on it.  I would however recommend you lock down those objects with proper profiles/roles/permissions so that even in the portal a user does not have access to all of everything.  Otherwise you may end up being forced to do manually checking of permissions before displaying records.

Comment: Thanks Mike...I ended up changing the security setup and used high volume portal user licenses. They come with an out of the box setting to limit record usage by Account.